# Jest test not resetting mock value properly

Tags: javascript, reactjs, unit-testing, react-native

I'm trying to test a component's style prop, which changes depending on the return of a function called `isIphoneX`. Because of that, I wrote 2 test cases, where I mock the return value of that function differently for each. Therefore, I'm expecting the component to have a different style prop each time.

The first test passes (as isIphoneX gets evaluated to false) but the second test keeps getting 80 back, instead of the 110 for height.

Note that I have already attempted to use:

jest.clearAllMocks(), jest.resetAllMocks(), jest.resetModules(), outside, inside, and within beforeEach/afterEach.

I believe the issue has something to do with the component CameraOverlay running before the isIphoneX can be mocked.

```js
// CameraOverlay.js

import { isIphoneX } from 'utils/device';

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  capturePanel: {
    height: isIphoneX() ? 110 : 80,
  },
});

const CameraOverlay = () => (
  <View style={styles.capturePanel} testID="capturePanel">
    Some dummy text
  </View>
);

export default CameraOverlay;
```

```js
// CameraOverlay.test.js
import { shallow } from 'enzyme';
import CameraOverlay from 'components/CameraOverlay';
import { isIphoneX } from 'utils/device';

jest.mock('utils/device');


describe('<View style={styles.capturePanel} testID="capturePanel">', () => {
    let wrapper;
    beforeEach(() => {
      wrapper = shallow(<CameraOverlay {...defaultProps} />);
    });
    it('renders correct style height for standard devices', () => {
      isIphoneX.mockReturnValue(false);
      expect(
        wrapper.find({ testID: 'capturePanel' }).prop('style').height,
      ).toEqual(80);
    });
    it('renders correct style height for iPhone X (and newer) devices', () => {
      isIphoneX.mockReturnValue(true);
      expect(
        wrapper.find({ testID: 'capturePanel' }).prop('style').height,
      ).toEqual(110);
    });
  });
```

Comment: I wonder if it's because `isIphoneX` is actually being called when the file is imported, and not every time the component is rendered.

Comment: @MattyJ I believe it might be that. However, I'm not sure how to actually fix it - I've tried using a require() on the component, so that I can "import it" on each test, but I can't use shallow on it if I do that:

`const CameraOverlay = require( 'components/CameraOverlay');`

Comment: What about applying the conditional in the component instead of when the `CameraOverlay` is imported. Like `style={isIphonX() ? styles.capturePanelLarge : styles.capturePanel}`

Comment: @MattyJ Umm so that styles actually had like 100+ lines worth of code. The only style that changes depending on the isPhoneX return is that height.

Comment: The very first example here shows how to apply multiple styles by using an array in the style prop: https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/stylesheet.html
Maybe that will work?

Comment: Thank you, @MattyJ. I was able to use something similar to that to change the way I get that height

Comment: That’s great! 